# How to put background music correctly in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an game where I have implement a background music to play when they start playing the game, but for some reason I am getting an crash in viewDidLoad with the error code: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` . Can any one check what I have done wrong. I have `import AVFoundation` and declared `var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()`

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.createScene()

        // Playing Audio.
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:
                Bundle.main.path(forResource: "puzzle", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

            var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
           try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            }
            catch {

            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)


        }
       audioPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code executes just fine as long as there is a file called "puzzle.mp3" included in the app's bundle.

The error you're getting is most likely due to this:

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "puzzle", ofType: "mp3")!
```

You're force-unwrapping an optional `String`, which will be nil if the app is unable to find a resource called "puzzle.mp3" at runtime. That's probably happening because your mp3 is not getting copied into the bundle at compile-time.

To fix it, tell the compiler to add it to the bundle:

- Click your project in the left pane.
- Choose your target from the
  pulldown menu at top left.
- Click the "Build Phases" tab.
- Click "Copy Bundle Resources" to expand it.
- Click the plus sign and choose your mp3 to add it to the bundle.